# jQuery validation: not working with jQuery ready

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

jQuery validator not working with $.ready

Following code is at the end of document body.

```
<script src="lib/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="lib/validate/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="lib/validate/additional-methods.min.js"></script>

$().ready(function(){
    $( "#frm_register" ).validate(
    {
        rules: {
            contactpr: {
                required: true,
                number: true
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            cnic: {
                required: true,
                number: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            default: "Left empty"
        }
    });
});
```

When I removed $().ready statement it works fine, why ?

I am using ready to make sure that everything loads before validation applies.

Comment: If the code is at the bottom of the page, every DOM element will be ready, so there is no need for `.ready`. While `$().ready` is supposed to work, [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) says it is not recommended.

Comment: @FelixKling I have changed it to $(document).ready() and still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

You have Used

```
$().ready(function(){
    // Your Validation Code
});
```

It should be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// Your Validation Code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As already explained in other answers, your document `ready` event handler is not in the proper format.  Everything seems to be working fine when I use `$(document).ready(function(){})`

See:  http://jsfiddle.net/gep8U/

However, you also have this option defined:

```
    messages: {
        default: "Left empty"
    }
```

The `messages` option only takes a field `name` and rule (or a field `name` alone) along with the over-riding message.  Since there is no field `name` or rule called `default`, this option is doing nothing for you.

Try this instead:

```
    messages: {
        contactpr: {
             required: "Left empty"
        },
        email: {
             required: "Left empty"
        },
        cnic: {
             required: "Left empty"
        }
    }
```

**Working Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/47C7T/**